# Conditional find and replace

Tags: python, perl, sed, replace

I am trying perform a conditional find and replace in multiple files. Content of file could be,

```
$value$plusargs("DEC_ARG=%0d", val1);
$value$plusargs("HEX_ARG=%h", val2);
$value$plusargs("STRING_ARG=%s", val3);
```

Here I want to replace `$value$plusargs` by `get_dvalue_args` if there's `%0d`, by `get_hvalue_args` if `%h` and so on..

Desired output is,

```
get_dvalue_arg("DEC_ARG", val1);
get_hvalue_arg("HEX_ARG", val2);
get_svalue_arg("STRING_ARG", val3);
```

I have tried 'awk' command below but its replacing all lines with get_dvalue_arg,

```
awk '/=%0d/&&/$plusargs/{sub("$value$plusargs","get_dvalue_args")}1'
```

I also tried 'sed' command below but same result,

```
sed -i '/=%0d/{s/$value$plusargs/get_dvalue_args/}'
```

Note I could do this by vim recording but with that I have to modify each file one by one and I am looking for a better way to do it in one shot, targeting multiple files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sed that has a `-E` option to enable EREs, e.g. GNU or OSX/BSD sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/\$(value)\$plus(args\("[^=]+)=%0?(.)/get_\3\1_\2/' file
get_dvalue_args("DEC_ARG", val1);
get_hvalue_args("HEX_ARG", val2);
get_svalue_args("STRING_ARG", val3);
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\$\(value\)\$plus\(args("[^=]\{1,\}\)=%0\{0,1\}\(.\)/get_\3\1_\2/' file
get_dvalue_args("DEC_ARG", val1);
get_hvalue_args("HEX_ARG", val2);
get_svalue_args("STRING_ARG", val3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl oneliner

```
perl -pne "s/\$value\$plusargs(\(\"[A-Z_]+)=%\d?([a-z])/get_$2value_arg$1/;" data_file
```

Input

```
$value$plusargs("DEC_ARG=%0d", val1);
$value$plusargs("HEX_ARG=%h", val2);
$value$plusargs("STRING_ARG=%s", val3);
```

Output

```
get_dvalue_arg("DEC_ARG", val1);
get_hvalue_arg("HEX_ARG", val2);
get_svalue_arg("STRING_ARG", val3);
```